# DNS Server Related Query

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

In setting up an Active Directory domain controller, I have been asked the following question, and I'm unsure how to answer it. I was wondering if someone could help me?

"By default, the wizard configures this domain controller to function as a DNS server. Under what circumstances would it be practical not to configure this domain controller to be a DNS server?"

Cheers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about homework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For small networks there is no common reason to separate DNS and Active Directory.

If you were looking to utilize existing DNS infrastructure, it may not be worth having the AD DC be a DNS server. A university which primarily ran Linux infrastructure, for example, and all DNS was in BIND, having one or two Windows DNS servers would just be administrative overhead.  You'd be better off adding the service registrations to BIND for the new DC.

The same could also be said for performance reasons.  If you were running a network with 25,000 clients on it, the DS's at the top of the tree may be heavily loaded enough that placing DNS on another box could result in significant performance benefits.

Comment: Cheers for the answer, it makes more sense now!